# Xamarin - Generic Method For Checking Connectivity

Tags: c#, xamarin

When a client accesses different parts of the software and their internet connection stops working, the application would crash.

I have a bit of code to trigger when a new page is loaded, but the issue I come across at the moment is that it's a ton of pages to repeat the code on. Wondering if there's a more clean solution to check for connectivity. At the moment I have OnAppear for my root page, which covers returning back to the application but not when the application is in the foreground.

```
public partial class NotificationPage : ContentPage
{
    public NotificationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.Internet, AppResources.InternetConnectivity, AppResources.OK);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => App.Current.MainPage = NavigationPageHelper.Create(new RootPage()));
}
        else
        {
            BindingContext = new ContactListViewModel(Navigation, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can monitor for Connectivity changes in your App class, or build the check into a custom base page or VM class that your other pages and VM inherit from

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful .https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamariin-forms-check-internet-connection-using-xamarin-essentials/